# connecting to Oracle XE with myBatis using JDBC in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, oracle, maven, jdbc, oracle-xe

I'm using Eclipse with Maven, in myBatis-config.xml I have the following codes. The H2 part of the code works as I can connect to H2 with my program and access the database. The Oracle part of my code doesn't work. I'm using ORACLE DATABASE XE 11.2, application express with a workspace: test, username: name, password: 123. When I run a testing class in Eclipse, I could pass the H2 tests, but when I run the same test using oracle instead, it gets an error. "Error selecting key or setting result to parameter object. Case: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist.

```
<environment id="H2">
    <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
    <dataSource type="POOLED">
        <property name="driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9096/sample/testDB" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="123" />
    </dataSource>
</environment>

<environment id="ORACLE">
    <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
    <dataSource type="POOLED">
        <property name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
        <property name="username" value="system" />
        <property name="password" value="123" />
    </dataSource>
</environment>
```

Comment: If your username is "name", don't put "system" in the config. (Actually, don't do anything with system.)

Comment: tried it with name and 123, same error.

Answer (score -1):

Hello reading the documentation from the official site of MyBatis I could obtain the following information:

In case of using the multi-db feature you will need to inform the databaseIdProvider property in the following way:

In case of using the multi-db feature you will need to inform the databaseIdProvider property in the following way:

```
<bean id="vendorProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="SQL Server">sqlserver</prop>
            <prop key="DB2">db2</prop>
            <prop key="Oracle">oracle</prop>
            <prop key="MySQL">mysql</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="databaseIdProvider" class="org.apache.ibatis.mapping.VendorDatabaseIdProvider">
    <property name="properties" ref="vendorProperties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:sample/config/mappers/**/*.xml" />
    <property name="databaseIdProvider" ref="databaseIdProvider"/>
</bean>
```

Hope it has been helpful.

Greetings.

---

NOTE Since 1.3.0, configuration property has been added. It can be specified a Configuration instance directly without MyBatis XML configuration file. For example:
[mybatis.org/spring/es/factorybean.html](http://mybatis.org/spring/es/factorybean.html)